# prime faces jsf pages will not render on linux tomcat but will render on eclipse test env

Tags: spring, tomcat, primefaces

My first time posting so if i break the protocalls I apologise

I have created a project that runs Primefaces with Spring using Eclipse and a tomcat 6 server on windows the application runs perfectly fine, when the application is moved to the "live" server which is a linux box the screens will not display

All the libraries are copied over as they should be, when I try access the url on the linux box with the jsf extention(login.jsf) i recive a 404 error, when i try using the .xhtml extention (login.xhtml) i recive an xml view of the code

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jtLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
       </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

my login.xhtml

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          template = "template/template.xhtml">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" /> 


          <p:panel>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Username:"/>
                        <p:inputText value = "#{loginUI.username}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Password"/>
                        <p:password value = "#{loginUI.password}"/>


                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Login" actionListener="#{loginUI.login}" update="growl"/> 

          </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    [/code]
```

my faces config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <faces-config
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

         <application>
      <el-resolver>
              org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
      </el-resolver>
       </application>

    </faces-config>
```

when i start the tomcat there are no errors in the log

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in servlet

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
```

set

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

and in servlet

```
<servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
```

set

```
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
```

Comment: in your context-param is param-name javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE remove it from production version, but i don't think this is your problem. Could you add content of WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, url to which knock, and check the production server have open port on firewall